# Double thumbnails after adding custom wallpapers to /usr/share/backgrounds

Tags: desktop-background

I have followed the advice in various posts to this forum on how to get 12.04 to display my own wallpapers in `/usr/share/backgrounds`. None worked I have subsequently established that 12.04 uses file precise-wallpapers.xml to read its' wallpapers.

This file is locacted in `/usr/share/gnome-background-properties`. I have added mine to this file. My issue is that when I right click and select 'change background' I now have two thumbnails for my wallpapers. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: it might be that the xml file is updated on restart/logout thus causing a duplicate entry because of your manual modification of the file.

Comment: Hi Daniel. This occurred before I did a restart/logout.